# boxplots keep getting erased while codes are being executed

Tags: r, boxplot

I am using the following code to produce 4 boxplots in a single graph which involves rearranging and coloring each boxplot :

```
boxplot(glucose~treatments,data=F1FG,xlab="Treatment diets",ylab="Glucose(mg/dL)",main="F1")

F1FG$treatments<-ordered(F1FG$treatments,levels=c("NM","LM","CM","HM"))

order<-as.factor(rep(c(3,4,2,1),each=33))

F1FG<-cbind(F1FG,order)

colours=c(rep("orange",1),rep("pink",1),rep("white",1),rep("blue",1))

boxplot(glucose~treatments,data=F1FG,xlab="Treatment diets",ylab="Glucose(mg/dL)",main="F1",col=colours)
```

I have been using these commands for a long time and they worked perfectly. All of a sudden, by the time I reach the last line of code, the graph with the boxplots just get erased from the screen while being executed. Is there a problem with my code or is there something wrong with the the importing of the file?

Comment: `boxplot` and `plot` and similar are "high-level" plotting commands. they will ignore what you have and create new plots instead. you can add to current ones usually by passing `new = TRUE` or `add = TRUE` depending on the function you're using or `par(new = TRUE)` should always work. That said, I don't understand why you want to use the final line--it looks exactly like the first one but with different colors. maybe you should *not* be using the first call to boxplot and just run from the seond line on?